# How to get App name in UITesting swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode-ui-testing

I tried to get my app name in UITesting. I tried the code below:

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
```

But it gives me the nil value result.

Comment: Did you set DisplayName from project setting of your APP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, that you've set Display name in your Info.plist file?
Just set this name in Project settings or in Info.plist:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. Already have added this in info.plist of UITest of Xcode. But its not working.

Comment: You should add this to Info.plist of your main app target, not in Testing target.. You sure you add this to your main target?

Answer (score 7):

When I was trying to find out if the 'debugDescription' provides any information about the actual app (and not the test app) I stumbled across a label that looked exactly like the app's display name.

I don't know if it helps you, but the following simple line of code helped me:

```
XCUIApplication().label
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will only work if your app is running, no?

Comment: @FlavioBittencourt Yes. But if you store that name in a let constant, and then terminate the app, and then use the name you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I am getting app name in UI test like this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
// ...
let appName = app.label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to File > Workspace Settings if you are in a workspace environment or File > Project Settings for a regular project environment.

Then click over the little grey arrow under Derived data section and select your project folder to delete it.

And Product > Clean.
It helps in many situations.